# How to sort objects by dynamical fields kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

I am wondering how to make sorting by dynamic field using kotlin .
Let's sat I have the following:

```
class Example(
  val prop1: String,
  val prop2: String,
  val prop3: Int,
  ....
  ....
  val prop100: String
)

fun sort(sortProperty: String, sortDirection: String) {
  return listOf(Example(), Example()).sortWith(compareBy(sortProperty, sortDirection))
}
```

How I can make a sorting by any field of **Example** class ?

Comment: probably you can use reflection

Comment: Are you trying to provide `Strings` that indicate `KPropertys` to sort on? Can you give a concrete example of a value for `sortProperty`? (Also, I don't think there's such a thing as a "dynamic field" in Kotlin.)

Comment: @EntangledLoops i'd like to have a possibility to be able to sort by any field of some class. sortProperty in that case is the field of class , it can be any primitive type. In javascript i can access any field of object by something like this **object[field]** and **field** in that case can be passed from outside a.k.a be dynamic .

Comment: @YuriyKorovko Okay, I understand you now. Just so you know, you cannot directly declare fields in Kotlin (see [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#properties-and-fields)). However, a property with a backing field accomplishes the same thing. I think you are trying to bend Kotlin to be too much like Javascript, and you would be better served by learning to solve your problem differently here. How would a `Comparator` compare objects of type `Any` in a meaningful way, here? By name or hashcode? Maybe explain what you are trying to accomplish exactly.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for the `sortedBy`, `sortedByDescending`, or `sortedWith` functions? (see the [Kotlin reference guide](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collection-ordering.html) for examples)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve that like this

```
class MyComparator(
   private val sortProperty: String? = null,
   private val isAscending: Boolean
): Comparator<Data> {

override fun compare(o1: Data?, o2: Data?): Int {
    val kProperty1 = Data::class.declaredMemberProperties.firstOrNull { it.name == sortProperty }
    return if (kProperty1 != null) {
        val valueFirst = kProperty1.get(o1!!).toString()
        val valueSecond = kProperty1.get(o2!!).toString()
        if (isAscending) valueFirst.compareTo(valueSecond) else valueSecond.compareTo(valueFirst)
    } else {
        val idProperty = Data::id
        val valueFirst = idProperty.get(o1!!)
        val valueSecond = idProperty.get(o2!!)
        if (isAscending) valueFirst.compareTo(valueSecond) else valueSecond.compareTo(valueFirst)
    }
}
```

}

From the code:

```
totalResults.sortedWith(comparator = MyComparator(sortProperty, isAscending))
```